# Why can't an array's newly hand-assigned value in an array not inherit values from its brothers?

Tags: php, arrays

I have an array like this:

```
return [
    [ 'file_name' => basename( $path['path'] ) ],
    [ 'file_path' => str_replace( basename( $path['path'] ), '', $path['path'] ) ]
];
```

Problem is, I have to repeat that `basename( $path['path'] )` which is not optimized. Here are my thoughts:

The easy way is, I could definitely assign that to a variable, but, because I am calling `basename[ $path['path']`, it has to have been created somewhere in memory already and I must have a pointer to it, somewhere.

The biggest issue with this that I see that each item in an array is its own part in memory and holds an unique value, if my second item in that array was to mime a brother value from the same array, would the later also update when the brother he mimes also updates?

So, ideally, what I'd look for is:

```
return [
    [ 'file_name' => define( ],
    [ 'file_path' => str_replace( basename( $path['path'] ), '', $path['path'] ) ]
];
```

My problem is that I'm about to build a big array like this and I don't feel assigning these values to a variable just so I could use them in 2 places.

What is there to do?

Comment: Why not use `dirname`? or something like `$x = ['a' => $b = 4, 'b' => $b + 2 ];` works...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
return [
    [ 'file_name' => $expensive = expensive( $path['path'] ) ],
    [ 'file_path' => str_replace( $expensive, '', $path['path'] ) ]
];
```

I wouldn't shy away from sparsely used variables.

Comment: What the...why did I never think of this?

Comment: First comment is getting at this. (Nick.)

Comment: @Nick Yup, saw, sorry.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your requirements, you can just use the single call of `pathinfo()`.

```
$path_parts = pathinfo('/www/htdocs/inc/lib.inc.php');
return [
    [ 'file_name' => $path_parts['basename'] ],  // lib.inc.php
    [ 'file_path' => $path_parts['dirname'] ]  // /www/htdocs/inc
];
```

http://php.net/manual/en/function.pathinfo.php

Or if you want to go "really simple", just explode on the last `/` and store that data.

Comment: Oh, no, how do I put it...my question is simply about why can't I just refer to, in a new value of the same array, to a past value of the same array.

Comment: the storage in an array is static data.

Comment: Naturally, but that's my question in essence - is it possible to somehow create re-usable data so that repetion / re-execution doesn't happen?

Comment: Well, if this was my task, I would avoid the bloat and just store the full filename and path as a whole string.  Then when I have a program that wants to use a substring of the string, it only has to call the correct function.  This spares memory and reduces overall array complexity.

Comment: @coolpasta No matter what you decide to do, please progress this page to a system-recognized resolution.  If you would like answer refinement/clarification, please ask for it.